# Add column to the dataframe containing the toJSON() of other column's value

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to achieve something relatively simple - I want to take a dataframe and add to it a column which would contain a value from the same row parsed with `jsonlite::toJSON()`. I'm trying to achieve that using `dplyr::mutate()`:

```
iris %>% dplyr::mutate(species_json = jsonlite::toJSON(Species))
```

The problem with this approach is that `Species` in the `toJSON`'s context is the whole *Species* column, not the value of the current row so in resulting df in each row there is a very log JSON string.

How can I accomplish what I want? I was trying to use `dplyr::row_number()` but inside `toJSON` everything is recognized as a whole, not in the current row's context.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? `iris %>% rowwise %>% dplyr::mutate(species_json = jsonlite::toJSON(Species))`

Comment: @Ben yes, exactly! Thank you,